# 160 GB drive reporting at 60 GB

Tags: disk-image

I have a 160 gigabyte western digital drive, after drive imaging it will only report 60 gigs as existing (the size of the drive I imaged onto it) the remaining space does not show up as un-allocated, or available, the drive itself has become convinced it is only 60 GB.

How do I re-initialize the drive and reset it to the correct size? I am okay with destroying all the data, I just want the drive to report its size correctly.

Comment: Software to image? OS?

Answer (score 2):

What did you use to image it? I get the same effect with Clonezilla.

Not a big deal though. Just get a [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) boot disk and use it to resize the partition.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you use a disk imager. It creates an exact copy of the disk on the new disk, including but not limited to the exact size of the disk, I think through the partition table.

You're better off copying the contents of the drive from the old one to the new one. There are utilities that can perform this kind of backup much better than whatever disk imaging software you used.

Comment: Almost all disk imaging software is capable of expanding the partition to the full size of the new drive automatically.